# Initialize an Instance with Type in Dart

Tags: types, dart, flutter

Assume I have some `Type` instances:

```
final strType = String;
final intType = int;
```

I want to initialize instances of the `Type`s, for example, preferably,

```
final myString = strType(); // myString is String()
```

or

```
final myInt = new intType(); // myInt is int()
```

However, the compiler raised an error of `strType isn't a function`.

Is it possible to initialize an instance of a `Type` in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the language level. It is possible with reflection, but the code will be complex and to use it on the web or flutter it would require codegen.

Instead of assigning a `Type` to a variable, consider assigning a function type. `() => SomeClassName()` is an anonymous function that can create an instance of `SomeClassName`.